# I am unsure what I am doing wrong with difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The first one is:
$x(n+2) - 4x(n) = 27n^2$, $x(0) = 1$, $x(1) = 3$.

So I work out the complimentary and particular solutions and add them, and I get:

$$x(n) = 5(2)^n + 2(-2)^n - 9n^2 + 12n - 6.$$

However, because I was unsure, I used this to check https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(0)%3D1,+g(n%2B1)%3Dn%5E2%2Bg(n)&lk=3

and it says the answer is:

$$x(n) = \frac14 (e^{2 i \pi n} (-9 n^2 + 6 n + 1) + 43 \cdot 2^{n + 1} - 2^{n + 1} e^{i \pi n} - 27 (n (n + 2) + 3))$$

I also have a problem with:

$$x(n+1)-4x(n)+3x(n-1)=36n^2$$

When solving for the constants in the particular, I am getting $0=36n^2$,
and because of this, I feel that I am missing something.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As a start, you know that $e^{2\pi i n} = 1$ and $e^{\pi i n} = -1$.  Maybe you can simplify the answer from Wolfram a bit now.

Comment: 1. $\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i \pi n} = 1, \mathrm e^{\mathrm i \pi n} = (-1)^n$. 2. If you cannot get a feasible solution for the particular ones, raise the greatest power [2 to 3] and do it again.

Comment: So I have tried simplifying using  e2πin=1 and eπin=−1, I end up getting -9n^2 + 12n + (-1)^n * 2^(n-1) -43 * 2^(n-1) +20

Comment: I've managed to do it now, I realised I made a very stupid mistake, thank you for the help